# HTTPPOST request is not been Hit by API, but the same API is working from POSTMAN

Tags: asp.net, api, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am calling an HTTPPOST method using ionic, this same APIis working using REST API Testing Tool POSTMAN, But this API is not been hit by Angular POST Requset

Ionic Code is below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:52998/api/Default/login';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  login(credentials) {
    debugger;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(apiUrl+'AddEmployee', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }
```

My ASP.NET API code looks Like below

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    //int maxId = listEmp.Max(e => e.ID);
    //employee.ID = maxId + 1;
    //listEmp.Add(employee);


    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=DESKTOP-M68F6NP;Database=DBCompany;Integrated Security=true";

    //myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=DESKTOP-M68F6NP;Database=DBCompany;Integrated Security=true"; working sql connections
    //SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblEmployee (EmployeeId,Name,ManagerId) Values (@EmployeeId,@Name,@ManagerId)", myConnection);
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblEmployee (EmployeeId,Name,ManagerId) Values (@EmployeeId,@Name,@ManagerId)";
    sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;


    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", employee.EmployeeId);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", employee.Name);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerId", employee.ManagerId);
    myConnection.Open();
    int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

As soon as the API is been called my IONIC, I get see an Increment in Application Insight from last Debug above the Controller name, Please Help me Figure it out, The Screenshot of the image is here:
[image: The Screenshot of the image is here]

Comment: Your api url will endup like `http://localhost:52998/api/Default/loginAddEmployee` which seems invalid. Please ensure your api url is correct.

Comment: I think in your APIURL u need to add "/" after login that is missing and if that is not the issue please post error whiuch you are get in response of API call.

Comment: It can be a CORS error. Have you tried running your app on browser with CORS extension enabled ?

Comment: i have not enable CORS Extension , Should i have do that ..@Shrutika Patil

Comment: yeah.!That Api is working fine with posting paramenter with POSTMAN "http://localhost:52998/api/Default/loginAddEmployee" @ Mohsin Mehmood

Comment: STATUS 404 ..@CodeChanger

Comment: @santhoshs 404 error indicates that url is not valid. `localhost:52998/api/Default/loginAddEmployee` while your action method name is `AddEmployee`. Can you share your controller class declaration and what attributes you have on the controller class?

Comment: public class Employee
                    {
                        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
                        public string Name { get; set; }
                        public int ManagerId { get; set; }

                        public string username { get; set; }
                        public string password { get; set; }
                        //public string Department { get; set; }
                        //}
                    }

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z6iW7wztAi1ZFyMNrWSzFuFp-nbUEZwi

Comment: i have enabled CORS extension in my Chrome Browser,still same unresponsiveness is been Shown by API  @Shrutika Patil